# org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.nextTimestamp

Tags: java, hibernate

Please Help:
Below error when I tried to add details to tables using hibernate:

```
NullPointerException
org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.nextTimestamp(RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.java:93)
SessionFactoryImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:639)
SessionFactoryImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:648)
com.package1.service.AuthenticateUser.addUser(AuthenticateUser.java:32)
com.package1.controllers.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:68)
```

**AuthenticateUser:**

```
public class AuthenticateUser {


public void addUser(String uname, String uemail, String usrnme,
        String upass) {
    Session session = factory.openSession();    //Line No:32
    Transaction txn = session.beginTransaction();
    user.setName(uname);
    user.setEmail(uemail);
    user.setUsrname(usrnme);
    user.setPassword(upass);
    txn.commit();
    session.save(user);
    session.close();
    factory.close();
}

private static SessionFactory factory = HibernateSessionManager
        .getSessionFactory();
private User user = new User();
```

}

In LoginServlet I call 
authenticateUser.addUser("abcdef", "abcdef","abcdef", "abcdef");

Comment: One Possible Reason is that you are committing your transaction before saving the object. Which is Totally Wrong. Write the line **`txn.commit();`** after **`session.save(user);`**

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the factory object, so attempting to open a session with it has chances to cause such a crash (on next call).

Remove this line :

```
factory.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert this order:

```
 txn.commit();
 session.save(user);
```

Like this:

```
   session.save(user);
   txn.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

this error ocurrs when you try to **create** an EntityManager with a ***closed*** EntityManagerFactory.

So, the recomandation is,

- **EntityManagers** must be ephimerals *create and close only in the scope of the transaction.
- **EntityManagerFactory** must be application scoped.

  NullPointerException
  org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.nextTimestamp(**RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.java:93**)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).